# how to change particularly one row textview value while click the button in custome listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom list view with base adapter. i have tried to increment and decrement particularly one row textview value. it is working but all the row textview value is changed while click the button. how can i changed particularly one row textview value. plese suggest me.

```
public class BreakfastListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] number;
    private int[] imageid;

    ImageView plus1, minus1;
    TextView value1;
    int a = 0;

    public BreakfastListAdapter(Context c, String[] number, int[] imageid) {
        context = c;
        this.imageid = imageid;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return number.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            // convertView = new View(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondadapter, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        plus1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        value1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
        textView.setText(number[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        value1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
        System.out.println(a + "dddddddddddddd");

        plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + 1;
                value1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(a), 1000).show();
                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                System.out.println(a);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add one more Custom Class which takes record of particular row value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the value for each row and not one for all the rows.
Change your `int a` in an `int[] a` and keep each value of each row.

You will have the following listener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    a[position] = a[position] + 1;
    value1.setText(String.valueOf(a[position]));
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(a[position]), 1000).show();
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    System.out.println(a[position]);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public class BreakfastListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;
private String[] number;
private int[] imageid;

ImageView plus1, minus1;
TextView value1;
int a[];

public BreakfastListAdapter(Context c, String[] number, int[] imageid) {
    context = c;
    this.imageid = imageid;
    this.number = number;
    this.a = new int[number.length];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return number.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        // convertView = new View(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondadapter, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    plus1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    value1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
    textView.setText(number[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    value1.setText(String.valueOf(a[position]));
    System.out.println(a[position] + "dddddddddddddd");

    plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a[position] = a[position] + 1;
            value1.setText(String.valueOf(a[position]));
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(a[position]), 1000).show();
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            System.out.println(a[position]);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
    return convertView;


   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setText string to perticular row TextView.

Every row is referenced through **convertView** so we will use it

Modification is :

```
  plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            a = a + 1;
            // this is change
            convertView.value1.setText(String.valueOf(a));

            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(a), 1000).show();
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            System.out.println(a);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

We need to set **a** value to **0** at last :

```
// reset a value at end of getView() method
a = 0;
```

**So that when next row is displayed, a value is 0 and it starts increment from 0**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  remove

```
a = a + 1;//because this is a global variable in the class
        change value1.setText(""+(a+1));
```

if this's not the problem declare an array/arraylist with size similar to listview size and populate arraylist inside the constructer with all values set to 0.Then inside getview() method

```
int currentposition=position;
plus1.setTag(currentposition);
value1.setText(arraylist.get(currentposition));

 plus1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

int btnvalue=Integer.parseInt(plus1.getTag().toString());
arraylist.set(btnvalue,(Integer.parseInt(arraylist.get(btnvalue)))+1);
notifydatasetchanged();

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement ViewHolder Class to maintain a separate copy of their widgets for example

```
  ViewHolder{

    TextView t1;
    Imageview i1,i2;

    }
     @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       ViewHolder holder;


            if (convertView == null) {

                 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondadapter, null);

               holder = new ViewHolder();

               holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
               holder.i1  =convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
               holder.i2  =convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

               convertView.setTag(holder);


            }else
        {

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

         } 

            holder.t1.setText(number[position]);
            holder.i1.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
            holder.t1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
            System.out.println(a + "dddddddddddddd");

            holdert1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    a = a + 1;
                    holder.t1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(a), 1000).show();
                    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                    System.out.println(a);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
            return convertView

}
```